# TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' [discord.Permissions.update()]

Tags: python, discord.py

Im having problems while updating the role permissions, command is `!admin @[user]`. The error is in the title

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def admin(ctx, *, user = discord.Member):
    rand = random.randint(0, 1024)
    author = ctx.message.author
    role2 = await client.create_role(author.server, name=f"{rand}", colour=discord.Colour(0x010101))
    await client.edit_role(server=author.server, role=role2, permissions=discord.Permissions.update(administrator=True))
    await client.add_roles(user, role2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your converter should use `:` instead of `=`,

Instead of editing the permissions of the role, you can just provide the correct permissions when you make the role:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def admin(ctx, *, user: discord.Member):
    rand = random.randint(0, 1024)
    author = ctx.message.author
    perms = ctx.message.server.default_role.permissions
    perms.update(administrator=True)
    role2 = await client.create_role(author.server, name=f"{rand}", colour=discord.Colour(0x010101), permissions=perms)
    await client.add_roles(user, role2)
```

Comment: That works but thats not what I want, that removes all permissions and only allowing administrator, I want the default permissions (@everyone) and then add the Administrator permission

Comment: Administrator should override all the other permissions.  Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: I used it as an example, please can you fix it?

Comment: Sure.  The defaults will just be what the `@everyone` role already has though: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#create-guild-role